# Difference between GMap2 and google.maps.Map

Tags: google-maps

This might sound very dumb question but I am just confused. I am quite new in Google Maps and I had gone through two different types of mapping object namely GMap2 and google.maps.Map. What is the difference and which is better?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GMap2 is from previous version of google maps framework (version 2.x). Google has completely rewritten its maps javascript library, making it more lightweight and compatible with mobile devices. It's [version 3](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/).

If you are a beginner, start with version 3 (google.maps.Map)

Comment: ah okay thanks! so all my codes must be re-written if it is still in version 2?

Comment: if you will mix v2 and v3 code it potentially can create problems (here on SO are the examples of such can be found). For now API v2 is deprecated, but still working. So, if codebase is huge maybe you should not migrate immediately to v3. But of course no support, no bugfixes, and crowd of people using v2 is shrinking.